# Stored procedure data returned through ssms but not ef?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `GetSomeInfo()` stored procedure which returns data like this when I execute it directly in SSMS:

```
PRODUCT  PROFIT
Widget1  9.50
Widget2  10.50
Widget3  8.50
```

I've auto-genned an ORM with EF6 in my console app. An object reference to the stored procedure was generated and the following result type is returned:

```
ObjectResult<GetSomeInfo_Result>
```

However, I'm not sure how to access the stored procedure results from this return object. I tried creating a watch in the debugger to access different properties but I'm not having any luck in getting a handle to the actual data in this return object. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: post the code to call the stored procedure

Comment: You could possibly check out the [MSDN documentation on the   `ObjectResult` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739113%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and see what properties and methods it has, and you can even find a code example of how to access results .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just called ToList() on the result which gave me the info I needed